# Why doesn't Choco-solver find a solution?

Tags: choco

I'm learning to use [Choco-solver](https://choco-solver.org/). I found that it fails to find a solution to a very simple problem, which means that I must have misunderstood something...

I reduced my code to this:

```
    Model model = new Model("Minimum");
    IntVar x = model.intVar("x", 1, 9, false);
    IntVar y = model.intVar("y", 1, 9, false);
    IntVar z = model.intVar("z", -1000, 1000, false);

    z.eq(x.add(y.mul(2))).post();

    Solver solver = model.getSolver();
    solver.showStatistics();
    solver.showSolutions();
    solver.findSolution();
```

So, three integer variables and one constraint saying that `z = x + 2y`. Choco-solver responds `Complete search - No solution`.

I find that I get correct solutions if I change the inner part of the constraint from `y.mul(2)` to `y.mul(1)` (x = 1, y = 1, z = 2) or to `y.add(2)` (x = 1, y = 1, z = 4). I can even set it to `y.mul(-2)` (x = 1 y = 9 z = -17), but if I use `mul` with an integer larger than 1 the constraint seems to be unsolveable.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a bug in Choco Solver 4.10.7. This bug has been fixed since: https://github.com/chocoteam/choco-solver/issues/841

If you want to use the fixed version, I invite you to download the code from GitHub and compile it using Maven.

Concerning your constraint, I advise you to post an arithm constraint as following: `model.arithm(x, "+", y.mul(2).intVar(), "=", z).post();`. This way, you avoid having an intermediate variable corresponding to "x+2*y" that you force to be equal to z. It does not really matter in such a small example, but it could lead to memory issues on bigger problems while relying on ArExpression (for Arithmetical Expression).

Comment: Thank you, Arthur, and a huge thank you to you and to the rest of the Choco team for all the work you put in! I have built a new jar from the sources and everything works perfectly.